# When I put ParcelFileDescriptor into my MediaExtractor setDataSource(),cause IOException

Tags: java, android, h.264, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

I get video data from DatagramSocket,and it's a byte[] as we know,and I can't decode this byte[] exactly. so I have to used MediaExtractor to do this work.
here is my code:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    eosReceived = false;
    try {
        socket.receive(packet);
        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromDatagramSocket(socket);
        FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
        mExtractor.setDataSource(fd, 0, packet.getData().length);
        for (int i = 0; i < mExtractor.getTrackCount(); i++) {
            MediaFormat format = mExtractor.getTrackFormat(i);
            String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
            if (mime.startsWith(VIDEO)) {
                mExtractor.selectTrack(i);
                mDecoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "format : " + format);
                    mDecoder.configure(format, surface, null, 0 /* Decoder */);

                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "codec '" + mime + "' failed configuration. " + e);
                }
                mDecoder.start();
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It will go catch when code run over mExtractor.setDataSource(fd, 0, packet.getData().length); and the Exception is java.io.IOException: Failed to instantiate extractor.
I really have no idea to solve this problem....
by the way.It's work yesterday morning,but since yesterday afternoon,It doesn't work any more ....
please help,thanks a lot :)

Comment: tried `mExtractor.setDataSource(fd)`?

Comment: I'v tried this too . but It seems same...